# Application insights site extension in Azure causing high CPU usage with spikes?

Tags: azure-application-insights

After enabling Application Insights site extension in Azure (without doing any code level updates) for an app service the CPU for the app service plan goes up:

[image]

[image]

[image]

After disabling the Application Insights from each app service (and removing Application Insights applications) CPU gets back to normal

[image]

What could be the reason for this and how to troubleshoot the issue?

The app service plan is a P3V2 (840 total ACU, 14 GB memory, Dv2-Series compute equivalent). It runs both .NET Framework and .NET Core app services.

Comment: Are you turning on just Application Insights monitoring? Can you try disable things like Profiler, Details SQl query, SnapShotDebugger etc, and try to isolate the problem.

Comment: @thomius, there are multiple components behind "Turn on site extension" button, could you narrow down the issue by using "basic" mode?

Comment: We had a similar issue where the CPU was spiking with Application Insights in "Recommended" mode, the problem appeared to be the "Profiler" feature, we resolved the problem by changing to "Basic" Collection Level which disables the "Profiler" feature and has resulted in a significant reduction in the average CPU usage of our Web App. I have written a blog post where you can see the difference in CPU before and after: https://crm.webfletch.co.uk/posts/application-insights-causing-high-cpu-on-azure-web-app

Comment: Thank you for this. Finally allowed me to figure out why one application was always at around 30% CPU. Application Insights really needs to come with a health warning - can hurt your bank balance!!